# Generating a sine wave from a square wave, for a large frequency range

Tags: pwm, frequency

I have a PWM output from a micro controller.  I want to turn this into a sine wave.

The typical way to do this is a low pass filter.  Unfortunately, I want to change the PWM frequency, and the corresponding sine wave frequency, over more than a couple decades (say, 10Hz to 100kHz).  Are there any simple ways to do this?

Comment: No, there's not a simple filtering technique. For your application, you should look up Direct Digital Synthesis.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured that was the case, but wasn't sure if there was some kind of "square wave to sine wave" IC.

Comment: You could use a bank of digitally controlled filters, possibly.

Comment: @mkeith: that seems... much more complicated than other options. :)  wouldn't I need a (sharp) filter approximately every octave?

Comment: "I want to change the PWM frequency... more than a couple decades" - Why?

Comment: @BruceAbbott:  It isn't really relevant, but as the signal to drive a current source to for very low impedance measurements.  Then a lock-in to read the voltage.  The frequency scaling is to be able to avoid resonances or reactances when I'm just trying to read resistance.

Comment: Are you sure you couldn't just use the fastest PWM frequency at all times, and just vary the sine wave frequency instead of varying both PWM and sine frequencies? It is relevant in the sense that we often encounter people trying to do things they THINK they need to do, because of their flawed understanding of some other aspect of their problem (which they think is irrelevant). Not saying that is happening now. Just explaining why people ask.

Comment: "to be able to avoid resonances or reactances" - What resonances or reactances are you expecting?  How will you know that a particular frequency is avoiding them?

Comment: @mkeith:  Ah! I think I know what you are talking about.  I've been looking at the PWM signal as a square wave, but that doesn't have to be true.  That is my bad, I forgot about the terminology I was using.  You are right, I could keep the PWM frequency the same, vary the width to generate the sine wave, and then the lowpass would be the same regardless of the sin frequency.

Comment: @BruceAbbott:  Because I won't have phase shifts or gain and the gain and phase won't change locally with frequency (very much).  This is for a micro-ohm-meter for looking for shorts on boards: a capacitor or inductor somewhere that I am measuring could cause a resonance, giving a spurious signal.  A frequency dependent measurement will give better accuracy.  Ultimately, it doesn't matter.  I'm not asking for help with the project, I'm asking for help with this problem.  I appreciate you trying to figure out what the actual problem is, but I would have asked if that was what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what hardware you have available and how deep into software you want to go.

If you have the processing power and GPIO pins available, you can get away with a very cheap and simple R-2R ladder as your DAC (ditch the PWM). You can then use a sinewave LUT in your MCU's memory + a software defined Low Pass Filter. You can store multiple LPFs in memory/change the characteristics of it on the fly to get your desired frequency response. The output of the LPF can then be fed right to the R-2R ladder to generate your sinewave. This approach is a tradeoff between software complexity/processor power and flexibility/external component size and cost.

If you only have a few frequencies you want or creating a perfect sine-wave is not that important you could toggle between a few different external LPFs.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want , it can be done with a rather complex solution.

PWM to DC then [DC controlled Sine VCO.](http://www.linear.com/solutions/1471)

[image]

Comment: I was looking at VCOs,  This is an interesting option.